# How to read quoted string from File and write it without quotes?

Tags: python, file-io

I am trying to write a python script to convert rows in a file to json output, where each line contains a json blob.

My code so far is:

```
with open( "/Users/me/tmp/events.txt" ) as f:
        content = f.readlines()

# strip to remove newlines
lines = [x.strip() for x in content]

i = 1

for line in lines:
        filename = "input" + str(i) + ".json"
        i += 1
        f = open(filename, "w")
        f.write(line)
        f.close()
```

However, I am running into an issue where if I have an entry in the file that is quoted, for example:

```
client:"mac"
```

This will be output as:

```
"client:""mac"""
```

Using a second strip on writing to file will give:

```
client:""mac
```

But I want to see:

```
client:"mac"
```

Is there any way to force Python to read text in the format ' "something" ' without appending extra quotes around it?

Comment: "an entry in the csv"?  I don't see a CSV file here.  I don't see any file here; your posted code fails for lack of input.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: I tried a simple change to allow your code to run.  The result is that fail `input1.json' has your desired output, with no extra quotation marks.  i.e. I cant' reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of creating an auxiliary list to strip the newline from content, just open the input and output files at the same time. Write to the output file as you iterate through the lines of the input and stripping whatever you deem necessary. Try something like this:

```
with open('events.txt', 'rb') as infile, open('input1.json', 'wb') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        line = line.strip('"')
        outfile.write(line)
```